# Website shows webclient login

Tags: asp.net, webclient

I'm not experienced with ASP.NET and this problem I have is that whenever i enter my website domain it shows "WebClient Login" form instead of my website... But when I try my domain directly from the server where it is hosted, it works just fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably a DNS error. Can you add the domain to the question. Or the results of `dig mydomainname.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Running `dig www.shpejtimi.net` returns the following IP address:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.shpejtimi.net.  3599    IN  CNAME   shpejtimi.net.
shpejtimi.net.      3599    IN  A   46.99.168.125
```

Make sure that that is the value you expect to see. Try running `dig www.shpejtimi.net` on your server and see if it gives you the same results.

You may also be logged in on your server, which would avoid the WebClient login form. Try running an incognito browser window / use `curl www.shpejtimi.net` to check.